# merge pdfs with zendpdf

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I use zendpdf class to generate PDFs on a website an it works properly.
Now I'm trying to merge different pdfs with zendpdf and have an issue that always return in a blank PDF, but without any errors. This is my code:

```
$pdf_merged = new ZendPdf\PdfDocument();

$pdf_1 = new ZendPdf\PdfDocument();
$pdf_1->load("public/files/invoices/pdf1.pdf");
$pdf_2 = new ZendPdf\PdfDocument();
$pdf_1->load("public/files/invoices/pdf2.pdf");

foreach ($pdf_1->pages as $page){
    $pdf_extract = clone $page;
    $pdf_merged->pages[] = $pdf_extract;
}
unset($pdf_extract);

foreach ($pdf_2->pages as $page){
    $pdf_extract = clone $page;
    $pdf_merged->pages[] = $pdf_extract;
}
unset($pdf_extract);

$pdf_merged->save("public/files/invoices/MERGED.pdf");
```

I've also tried to use the Extractor class, but with same result:

```
$pdf_merged = new ZendPdf\PdfDocument();

$pdf_1 = new ZendPdf\PdfDocument();
$pdf_1->load("public/files/invoices/pdf1.pdf");
$pdf_2 = new ZendPdf\PdfDocument();
$pdf_1->load("public/files/invoices/pdf2.pdf");
$extractor = new ZendPdf\Resource\Extractor();

foreach ($pdf_1->pages as $page){
    $pdf_extract = $extractor->clonePage($page);
    $pdf_merged->pages[] = $pdf_extract;
}
unset($pdf_extract);

foreach ($pdf_2->pages as $page){
    $pdf_extract = $extractor->clonePage($page);
    $pdf_merged->pages[] = $pdf_extract;
}
unset($pdf_extract);

$pdf_merged->save("public/files/invoices/MERGED.pdf");
```

I've made some research (here and in zf2 manual) and apparently this solution should work, but it doesn't in my case.

Could it be a problem of PDF versions?

Tahnks in advance

Comment: You make a mistake you call twice `$pdf_1->load(...)`

Comment: You´re right. It was a mistake writing the post, but you solved me the problem with your last answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I know is that there are issues with pdfs larger then 5MB. Check the issue **[here on GitHub](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendPdf/issues/27).**

Not sure if what you are facing is the same problem. Did you try with smaller files?

According to the answers on GitHub the module is *"no longer maintained"*.
I am still looking for alternatives...

### EDIT

`ZendPdf\PdfDocument::load` is [a static method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). You can do like this:

```
use ZendPdf\PdfDocument;

...

$pdf_1 = PdfDocument::load("public/files/invoices/pdf1.pdf");
$pdf_2 = PdfDocument::load("public/files/invoices/pdf2.pdf");
```

Comment: Wow!, using that approach to load the documents the merge function works correctly. For the moment, my files are about 200K, so I will not have problems. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even if the PHP approach is nice to merge a PDF file there is a lot of inconvenients (library not maintained anymore, bugs, issues relative to PHP itself, performances...)

I give up PHP alternative to use [PDFUNITE](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/pdfunite.1.html).

This one is able to merge more than 5000 thousand PDF files(invoices in my production environnement) in less than 0.20 seconds. After that I couldn't go back to PHP.